# JSP Taglib PropertyNotFoundException

Tags: jsp, el

I have a variable named ***user*** in JSP. 
If I set ***user*** variable in mvc controller, I can handle ***${user.userNo}***.
On the contrary if I do not set user object, i can **not** use ${user.userNo}, and it throws PrpoertyNotFoundException.

I want to divide the two cases whether *user* is set or not. 
So I coded like below:

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${not empty user}">
        <c:set var="userNo"><c:out value="${user.userNo}" /></c:set>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <c:set var="userNo" value="anonymous" />
    </c:otherwise> 
</c:choose>
```

but the problem is that If I do not set ***user*** object, it doesn't forward to ***<c:otherwise>*** code. And it throws an exception because ${user.userNo} is not defined.

in similar case, it throws PropertyNotFoundException beacuse of ${user.userNo}

```
<c:if test="${not empty user">
<c:set var="userNo" value="${user.userNo}" />
</c:if>
```

It seems like every values used in EL expressions must be set before running the code.

Is there a way **not** to throw an exception when I do not set ${user} variable?

**EDIT**
part of error stack:

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path [/whiteboard] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.apache.tiles.impl.CannotRenderException: org.apache.tiles.util.TilesIOException: JSPException including path '/WEB-INF/views/tiles/contents/viewArticle.jsp'.] with root cause
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'userNo' not found on type java.lang.String
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver$BeanProperties.get(BeanELResolver.java:290)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver$BeanProperties.access$300(BeanELResolver.java:243)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.property(BeanELResolver.java:377)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:97)
    at org.apache.jasper.el.JasperELResolver.getValue(JasperELResolver.java:104)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:184)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:184)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.proprietaryEvaluate(PageContextImpl.java:950)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.tiles.contents.viewArticle_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fout_005f0(viewArticle_jsp.java:560)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.tiles.contents.viewArticle_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fset_005f0(viewArticle_jsp.java:533)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.tiles.contents.viewArticle_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fwhen_005f0(viewArticle_jsp.java:497)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.tiles.contents.viewArticle_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fchoose_005f0(viewArticle_jsp.java:460)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.tiles.contents.viewArticle_jsp._jspService(viewArticle_jsp.java:119)
```

Comment: `${user.userNo}` will try to use the getter `getUserNo()` of user, if you don't instanciate user, the property (the getter) can't exists. Basicly, this is a null pointer exception

Comment: Understood, then when I access to the page, without setting ${user} object from server-layer, how do I ignore the NullPointerException and continue to work on that page??

Comment: What about a simple  `user != null`

Comment: I tried that user!=null is equals to ${not empty user}. And the result is the same with second case above. Substituting ${user.userno} and access to <c:if> tag.